# Assert that a Mocked Validator has been processed

Tags: c#, moq, fluentvalidation

I'm trying to test FluentValidation validators with inheritance in the models.

Basically, I have a validator that applies some rules, before calling the parent class's validator for other rules. The parent validator is tested independently and there are no problems, so it's mocked in this particular test. But to make sure that my validator is working properly, I want to make sure that the parent validator is called correctly and that the test is carried out, without taking into account the result of the parent validator.

I think I've managed to reproduce the problem in the example below, with a check on the mock in the final test. But I don't have a real method to check, and I don't know enough about the `FluentValidation.TestHelper` to do that.

Please let me know if any information is missing.

```cs
public class Animal
{
    public string Name { get; }
}

public class Dog : Animal
{
    public string Color { get; }
}
```

```cs
using FluentValidation;

public class AnimalValidator : AbstractValidator<Animal>
{
    public AnimalValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(a => a.Name).NotEmpty();
    }
}

public class DogValidator : AbstractValidator<Dog>
{
    public DogValidator(IValidator<Animal> animalValidator)
    {
        RuleFor(a => a.Color).NotEmpty();               // One specific rule
        
        RuleFor(a => a).SetValidator(animalValidator);  // The parent validator checking additional rules
    }
}
```

```cs
using FluentValidation.TestHelper;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Moq;

[TestClass]
public class DogValidatorTest
{
    private readonly Mock<IValidator<Animal> _animalValidator;
 
    public DogValidatorTest()
    {
        _animalValidator = new Mock<IValidator<Animal>>();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public async Task ValidateAsync_EmptyParameters_ShouldHaveValidationErrors()
    {
        // Arrange
        var dog = new Dog("", "");
        var dogValidator = new DogValidator(_animalValidator.Object);

        // Act
        var validationResult = await dogValidator.TestValidateAsync(dog);

        // Assert
        validationResult.ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor(a => a.Color);                     // Works fine
        _animalValidator.Verify(mock => mock.Validate(It.IsAny<Animal>()), Times.Once);  // Called 0 times instead of 1
    }
}
```